# Granting a user permissions to PS Remote without allowing RDP

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Is there a way I can grant a user the ability to use Invoke-Command in PowerShell remotely without giving them RDP Access to the server?

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579255.aspx#BKMK_WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_), you don't want to add the user to the Remote Management Users group. You want to add the user to the WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_ Group. WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_ Group will give the user the ability to run remote PowerShell commands. Remote Management Users Group is for managing the server using Server Manager.

Comment: It seems like that did not help.
I got "access denied" when using only this group.